# Universal cartier divisor and blow up of base scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a projective variety over an algebraically closed field $k$, and $L$ be a line bundle on $X$, and $V \subseteq \Gamma(X,L)$ be a linear system. We have two families over projective space described below.

1. The universal cartier divisor $D \subseteq X\times \mathbb{P}(V)$ given by $(x,s)$ such that $s(x) = 0$.
2. We have a rational map from $X$ to $\mathbb{P}(V^\vee)$ defined by the linear system $V$,
   defined as $x \mapsto \{s: s(x) = 0\}$. Then we blow up the base locus of $V$ to get a map $\widetilde{X} \to \mathbb{P}(V^\vee)$.

Is there any relationship between $D$ and $\widetilde{X}$? If we take a basis of $V$ we yield two families over $\mathbb{P}^n$. It seems too much to expect they are always isomorphic, but I'd like to know if they are indeed isomorphic under some good situation, such as the base scheme being a regular immersion. Especially the case $\dim V = 2$ (a pencil) is interesting since we have a canonical isomorphism $\mathbb{P}(V) \simeq \mathbb{P}(V^\vee)$.

Comment: First of all, since $D$ is an effective divisor on $X \times \mathbb{P}(V)$, we will only have that $\dim D = \dim X$ when $V$ defines a pencil. Do you have a reason to think $D$ and $\tilde{X}$ are isomorphic in this case?

Comment: @Daniel Thanks for pointing out that we should consider pencil only. The projection from a point from plane to projective line provides an example of $D \simeq \tilde X$. After some calculation, I now believe that if $s_0,s_1$ are sections of line bundle that generate a regular sequence (in any trivialization), then $D \simeq \tilde X$.